# Is it possible to prove that a triangle has 180 degrees, without using parallel line properties?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, alternative-proof

Please make the proof as simple as possible; I'm still a beginner. Or rather, it's fine if you make it complex, but try to explain it using layman's language.

Comment: No, because it is not true in geometries that don't have the parallel line property (Euclid's fifth postulate.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Even going beyond Euclid (who, frankly, were in the right track, but couldn't hold up to the late 19th century rise in demand for mathematical rigor), the parallel postulate is an important part of geometric systems such as the one by Hilbert for defining what we intuitively know as Euclidean geometry. Without it, we can prove the existence part of the parallel postulate, but not the uniqueness. We can prove that triangles have an angle sum of _at most_ $180^\circ$, but not exactly $180^\circ$.

Comment: I dpn't see what the point is of your comment. What point do you think i am making? @Arthur

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Putting too much faith in Euclid as the basis for geometry (that was just the bracketed part, though). Apart from that, it's not a response to you, but rather expanding on your comment.

Comment: @Arthur That's not what I said at all. My argument is entirely a mathematical one. There are things which satisfy all of the postulates other than the parallel postulate, and, in some of those, there are triangles which do not add up to 180 degrees.  So you can't prove it with only the other axioms. What "faith" has to do with it is unclear to me.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think you put too much weight on a relatively small and somewhat unimportant part of my original comment. I noted that you mentioned Euclid, so I thought it worthwhile to point out that _technically_, Euclid is outdated and there are more modern axiomatic approaches. But even though we've managed to do "better" than Euclid, the parallel postulate is still indispensable. _That_ was my main point.

Comment: You recently asked essentially the same question here, where I suggested an answer.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807341/are-the-proofs-for-the-properties-of-parallel-lines-and-that-a-triangle-has-180 . That is really bad manners on this site, because it wastes the time of people who try to help. I will vote to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The essential way to prove "Theorem A can't be proved in axiom set X" is to find a "thing" (called a model) which satisfies the axiom set X in which A is not true.

There are models, like the [Poincaré disk model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model), in which have "points," "lines," "angles," etc., which we can prove satisfy all the properties of Euclidean geometry other than the parallel postulate.

In the Poincaré model, the angles of a triangle always add up to less than $180^\circ.$

Answer (score 0):

If it was possible, then the theorem would be true on the surface of a sphere. But it is not. It's easy to define a triangle there such the sum of all its internal angles is $270^\circ$, for instance. (Acutally, the sum will *always* greater than $180^\circ$.)

Comment: The sphere does not satisfy the rest of Euclid's postulates, though, since there are multiple lines (great circles) for anti-podal points.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I know that, but it is still possible (and it is likely, in my opinion) that this example is enough for the OP. However, if the OP says the same thing as you, I will delete it.

Comment: I think the Poincaré disc, while possibly not as well known, would be a more correct counterexample, as we there actually _do_ satisfy all the other axioms of Euclidean geometry (even more modern systems than Euclid's own).